# How to disable the ability to click on the JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea

I need to disable the ability to click your mouse in the JTextArea.

Below is what I currently have for my JTextArea:

```
textArea1 = new JTextArea();
textArea1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) textArea1.getCaret(); // this line and the line below was inspired by a comment found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623287/how-to-always-scroll-to-bottom-of-text-area
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
textArea1.setEditable(false);
JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(textArea1)
```

Once you press on the JTextArea with your mouse, it almost stops the whole DefaultCaret method from working. I thought previously it was because you could highlight but that was not the case.

The DefaultCaret method causes the JTextArea to always be at the bottom when new text gets added to the textarea.

Answer (score 1):

```
textArea1.setEnabled(false); // text area can neither be entered nor text selected
```

[image]

The caret is shown where it defaults to, being the first focusable component.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! When I have it set to disabled it still allows the user to click inside the textArea.

Comment: *"Thank you for the comment!"* You're welcome, but that was an answer. This (and yours that I just copy/pasted) is a comment. *"When I have it set to disabled it still allows the user to click inside the textArea."* I'm surprised! It does not have that behavior here. Please edit the question to show a [mre] that does show that behavior for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 2 things:

- Add setFocusable(false)
- if that doesn't work: use the methods removeMouseListener and getMouseListeners on your text area

Comment: Thank you for this, going to try this out now.

Comment: So the first option does not work as it seems to mess with the caret method used to always keep the viewpoint at the bottom. The second one should work but it does not and would be awesome if you could help me figure out why. I used the code below to remove the listeners: 
        textArea1.removeMouseListener(textArea1.getMouseListeners()[0]);
        textArea1.removeMouseListener(textArea1.getMouseListeners()[1]);
but still the same issue. If I click in the textArea1 it just ignored the whole caret method.